# Symphony CMS File Upload Fatal Error

Tags: symphony-cms, opensymphony

I am simply trying to create a section that allows me to upload a file, specifically an image. I am able to create the section without any problems. The issue is when I make a new entry and choose the file. When I click save, to save the entry, I receive a very strange error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function finfo_open() in
/home/jonlev19/jonathanlevis.dreamhosters.com/symphony/lib/toolkit/class.general.php
on line 934
```

I've searched around but have been unsuccessful in finding a solution to the problem. Does anyone have any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [enable the Fileinfo PHP extension](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/PHP.ini#Loading_PHP_5.3_Extensions).

[Dreamhost instructions here](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/PHP.ini#Loading_PHP_5.3_Extensions). ;-)